# Add 30 days on the current date we choose and display in a new field

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to add 30 days in date field in `sale.order` in **OpenERP v.7**
Actualy I did it but the problem is that I want that 30 days to be added on the date I choose in other date field not just to add a 30 days on today's date.

The Date field is `date_order`. When I choose a date, I want that 30 days to be added on the chosen date. In the code I make it to add that 30 days on today's date but I want it on the date I am choosing automatically to be changed 30 days later.

```
class Sale_Order(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

_columns = {
    'duedate': fields.date('Duedate', readonly=True),

}
_defaults = {
    'duedate': (date.today() + timedelta(days=30)).strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT),
}
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you need override create/write methods to change "duedate", if was changed date field.
But you can also describe duedate as functional field (stored in table or not).

Method to retrieve date:

```
def _get_due_date(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    ...
```

Field description:

```
'duedate': fields.function(_get_due_date, type='datetime', string="Due date"),
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieve, You need to Make **duedate** field as compute type

Example:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

Define duedate as compute field

```
duedate = fields.Date(string='Duedate', compute='_compute_duedate')
```

Define Compute Function

```
@api.multi
def _compute_duedate(self):
   for rec in self:
       rec.duedate = date.today() + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

Hope this help you.